# Type Parameter in Case Class Using Trait w/ Implicits

Tags: scala

Let's say we have a trait:

```
trait ThingToThing[-A, +B] { def apply(a: A): B }
```

and its companion object:

```
object ThingToThing {
  implicit object StringToBoolean extends ThingToThing[String, Boolean] {
    override def apply(a: String): Boolean = a.toBoolean
  }
}
```

and a case class:

```
case class Thing[A](a: A) {
  def to[B](implicit thing: ThingToThing[A, B]): B = thing(a)
}
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
Thing("true").to[Boolean]
res0: Boolean = true
```

This is all fine and dandy, and I can do something like:

```
case class MyClass(ss: Seq[String]) {
  def doStuff(s: String) = Thing(s).to[Boolean]
}
```

But what I'd like to do, however, is something like:

```
case class MyClass[B](ss: Seq[String]) {
  def doStuff(s: String) = Thing(s).to[B]
}
```

But, this errors with:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter thing: ThingToThing[String,B]
```

Is there a way I can use a type parameter in my `MyClass`?

** Don't get caught up on the toy example of converting a String to a Boolean; I just used this as a simple example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler couldn't find an implicit instance of `ThingToThing[String,B]` (`B` is unknown) in the call site `Thing(s).to[B]`:

```
case class MyClass[B](ss: Seq[String]) {
  def doStuff(s: String) = Thing(s).to[B]
}
```

thus the error.

You can declare the required implicit in the constructor to have it resolved in the call site of object creation (when `B` is known):

```
case class MyClass[B](ss: Seq[String])(implicit t2t: ThingToThing[String, B]) {
  def doStuff(s: String) = Thing(s).to[B]
}
```

, or declare it in the method to have it resolved in the call site of the method invocation (when `B` is known):

```
case class MyClass[B](ss: Seq[String]) {
  def doStuff(s: String)(implicit t2t: ThingToThing[String, B]) = Thing(s).to[B]
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!